# How do I call a function with UITextDocumentProxy as input?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function here where I would like to monitor the text box content for changing something else in the view. I need to call the result of this function into a variable so I can use it. I am getting multiple errors for multiple things I tried.

```
var temp = false

func UITextDocumentProxyIsEmpty(textDocumentProxy: UITextDocumentProxy) -> Bool {
    let precedingContext = textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput
    if precedingContext?.count == 0 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

temp = UITextDocumentProxyIsEmpty(..?????
```

Comment: Show what you have tried and what errors you are getting. Obviously you need to pass some of type `UITextDocumentProxy` to your `UITextDocumentProxyIsEmpty` function. Do you have such a value?

Comment: I added, (textDocumentProxy: textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput) it says type doesn't conform.
I don't know of any types, I am using this for the first time.
the only thing I tried didn't through error, but the app crashed when I ran it.
(textDocumentProxy: "" as! UITextDocumentProxy)